# Removing Paragraph Tags from get_the_excerpt($variable)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, parsing

Is there any way to remove the paragraph marks 

(probably created by some

tags wrapping the get_the_excerpt() method in wordpress)

??[image: paragraph marks html]

I am currently using: `$product_description = get_the_excerpt($product_id);`

I wanted to simply `echo <?php echo(get_the_excerpt()); ?>` **but it gives me a parsing error** because I have to enter it in a variable.

=> I guess **we can't echo when we define a variable.**

I am trying to retrieve my data from my product description but this wrapping kill my html tags. It's obvious but should looks like this:[image]

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: you can use `$product_description = get_the_excerpt($product_id)`

Comment: This is already what I am doing, which return me the above (first screenshot). I've edited sorry for the misunderstanding.